¿Cómo habilitar el scroll solo para un elemento table?
Tengo deshabilitado el scroll lateral para toda una aplicación:
    <div style="overflow-x: hidden;">
        <?= $this->include('menu'); ?>
        <?= $this->renderSection('contenido') ?>
    </div> 

Y quiero que se habilite solo para un elemento table cuando se supere el ancho de pantalla disponible:
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-hover" style="overflow-x: auto;">

No consigo que funcione este scroll lateral para este elemento table, aun cuando no cabe toda la información de la tabla en la pantalla.
Se agradece la ayuda.

Hola Jota, ¿podrías [edit] tu pregunta e incluir un [mcve]? Porque la respuesta que recibiste debería funcionar

Hola Marcos, perdona que sea tan escueto, pero es que no hay mucho mas. El caso es que en pantalla va bien, pero en dispositivos móviles no. Y no hay mas estilos aplicados. Gracias

Hola Jota, si en móviles no te funciona, es probable que se deba a que se están aplicando otros estilos. Esta situación sería bueno que la aclares, de lo contrario se vuelve difícil determinar el porqué no te funciona.

Las tablas no soportan la propiedad overflow, pero puedes conseguirlo del siguiente modo:

Puedes deshabilitar el scroll de tu aplicación en horizontal.
Dentro del 'div' inserta tu table y aplica la propiedad overflow-x: auto; a este contenedor.



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tabla con Scroll Horizontal</title>
    <style>
        /* Deshabilita el scroll lateral global */
        .main-container {
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        /* Contenedor de la tabla con scroll horizontal */
        .table-container {
            overflow-x: auto;  /* Permite el scroll horizontal */
            max-width: 100%;   /* Limita el ancho máximo del contenedor */
            margin: 0 auto;    /* Centra el contenedor horizontalmente */
        }

        /* Asegura que la tabla tenga un ancho fijo que pueda superar el contenedor */
        table {
            width: 1000px; /* Ancho fijo mayor al de la pantalla para forzar el scroll */
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        th, td {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="main-container">
    <!-- Menú y otras secciones de la aplicación -->
    <div>
        <p>Menú o contenido adicional aquí</p>
    </div>

    <div class="table-container">
        <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Columna 1</th>
                    <th>Columna 2</th>
                    <th>Columna 3</th>
                    <th>Columna 4</th>
                    <th>Columna 5</th>
                    <th>Columna 6</th>
                    <th>Columna 7</th>
                    <!-- Agrega más columnas si ves necesario -->
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Dato 1</td>
                    <td>Dato 2</td>
                    <td>Dato 3</td>
                    <td>Dato 4</td>
                    <td>Dato 5</td>
                    <td>Dato 6</td>
                    <td>Dato 7</td>
                    <!-- Agrega más datos si quieres.... -->
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Dato 1</td>
                    <td>Dato 2</td>
                    <td>Dato 3</td>
                    <td>Dato 4</td>
                    <td>Dato 5</td>
                    <td>Dato 6</td>
                    <td>Dato 7</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Agrega más filas -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>




ok gracias. Ya lo había hecho pero no funciona.

@Jota Afirmar que "no funciona" cuando su ejemplo lo ejecutas y claramente funciona... es raro, no?? Claramente algo no hiciste bien si afirmas que no te funcionó, porque efectivamente es como se hace normalmente puesto que las tablas no tienen overflow como tal

Ok, disculpa. No me funciona a mí solo con poner un container antes de la tabla y ahi habilitar el scroll. Tu ejemplo sí funciona perfectamente.
